# Solr - results stop in middle of word

Tags: solr, wildcard

Wasn't quite sure how to word the title of this. Basically, when I search for 'anim' it finds 'animals', however when I search for 'anima' it doesn't find anything. Then if I search for 'animal' it finds 'animals' again...

Does anyone have any ideas why it might not be working for 'anima'? It seems to happen for most words - but at different characters - e.g. 'eleph' and 'elephan' are fine - but 'elepha' doesn't return anything.

Here are the queries and results:

**Query 1 (okay)**

/solr/select?fq=type:tag&q=name:anim

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">1</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="fq">type:tag</str>
<str name="q">name:anim</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
<doc>
<int name="id">1</int>
<str name="name">Animals</str>
<arr name="name_auto">
<str>Animals</str>
<str>Animals</str>
</arr>
<date name="timestamp">2012-08-01T08:16:38.789Z</date>
<str name="type">tag</str>
<str name="unique_id">tag_1</str>
</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

**Query 2 (not okay)**

/solr/select?fq=type:tag&q=name:anima

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">1</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="fq">type:tag</str>
<str name="q">name:anima</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response>
```

**Query 3 (okay)**

/solr/select?fq=type:tag&q=name:animal

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">0</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="fq">type:tag</str>
<str name="q">name:animal</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
<doc>
<int name="id">1</int>
<str name="name">Animals</str>
<arr name="name_auto">
<str>Animals</str>
<str>Animals</str>
</arr>
<date name="timestamp">2012-08-01T08:16:38.789Z</date>
<str name="type">tag</str>
<str name="unique_id">tag_1</str>
</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

---

Edit 1:

**Field definition**

```
 <field name="name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

**fieldType:**

```
 <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
          add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
          analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Edit 2:

Passing strings though the Analyser:

- anim http://cl.ly/image/0B0s3k2x2Z0d
- anima http://cl.ly/image/3K1l1U140c2R
- animal http://cl.ly/image/0W3W0K2W1u3j

Comment: This is probably due to stemming. Put the words anim, anima, and animal into the Analyze box and see how they get stemmed. This isn't wildcard search because you're not adding a star after the search phrase.

Comment: I agree, could you post your `name` field definition (and related fieldType) from your Solr schema?

Comment: @javanna - see edit 1 above. Ansari, see edit 2 above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansari is right, the problem is due to stemming. The Solr schema you posted proves it since you're using the `PorterStemFilterFactory`. If you want to search for partial word you can try with wildcard queries, depending on the query parser you're using. If you're using SOlr 3.x they might be too slow, while with Solr 4.x this has been improved a lot. You might want to make [EdgeNGrams](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters/#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) then, so that `anima` match `animals` too.